# How to generate summary statistics if indicator variable is equal to 1?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data frame:

```
Layer       Grade              Players            NYAL 27
Top           A         NY 08; NY 27; NY 80          1
Bottom        D         MA 27; MA 45; MA 65          0
Middle        B         NY 09; MA 48; NY 66          0
Bottom        C         NY 06; NY 27; NY 80          1
...
```

I've been using the following code to generate summary statistics (count, %) for two separate categories.

```
df %>% 
count('NYAL 27',Grade, name = 'Count') %>% 
group_by('NYAL 27') %>% 
mutate(Perc = prop.table(Count) * 100)
```

'NYAL 27' is the name of a binary variable that indicates if that player is present in a given observation. The code is working right now, but it includes observations in the summary statistics where the indicator variable is equal to 0. I want to generate the same summary statistics but only if 'NYAL 27' is equal to 1.  How can I get it so it will only report summary stats if the indicator is equal to 1?

Desired output would look something like this, again, only if the indicator variable equals 1.

```
                    COUNT  PERC
 NYAL 27     A       1      50  
 NYAL 27     B       0       0  
 NYAL 27     C       1      50 
 NYAL 27     D       0      0
```

Comment: The 'NYAL 27' is not shown as a column in the input data

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(Grade) %>% mutate(Perc = mean(`NYAL 08` == 1))`

Comment: Just updated the post with desired output.

Comment: Are those numbers correct in 'COUNT' , 'PERC' based on the example

Comment: I just made them up. Just assuming NYAL 27 appeared 200 times in the dataset I just made up a distribution for Grade.

Comment: @akrun just a little confused--should I add your above code into my existing code or replace it entirely?

Comment: Can you please include bit more rows to make this reproducible so that I can match the values showed in expected.  Otherwise, solution may not get correctly tested

Comment: Hmm... I've had to adapt the DF so it would fit here and have had to change some of the language  in it. It's also 217 rows long by 60 columns wide so I cannot insert the entire thing. My apologies for that. If you do think you have a solution I can certainly test it myself in R. The code I initially posted works well, but again it just includes when the indicator variable is equal to 0. Sorry again

Comment: I didn't meant to show the whole example.  You can create a small example and the expecetd output based on that.  If you show 60, 50, etc on that example, it would make others confused. thanks

Comment: @akrun Ah ok I see what you mean. I made an edit that hopefully helps you out.

Comment: @akrun Typo. My mistake. Updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only 0/1 values in `'NYAL 27'` column calculate count and percentage of 1's in the data for each `Grade` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Grade) %>%
  summarise(Count = sum(`NYAL 27`)) %>%
  mutate(Perc = Count/sum(Count))
  #Or with prop.table
  #mutate(Perc = prop.table(Count))
```

Comment: How can I make the percentage column reflective the percentage breakdown when the indicator is positive? As it is right now, the percentage column reflects the percentage of times that the grade appears in the entire data set. I am looking for it to reflect the percentage of times that the grade appears when NYAL 27 is equal to 1.

Comment: Would it be possible to make it calculate for each grade exclusively for when the indicator variable is equal to 1? Right now it is giving me the % of grades  for the entire data set, not just when the indicator is one. So it counts the correct number of grades, but divides those grades by the full number of observations in the data set, as opposed to just the total number of grades when the indicator is one. As you might imagine, this lowers the percentages significantly.

Comment: I'm looking for a breakdown of grades for when NYAL 27=1. For example, if there are 5 'A' Grades, 10 'B' Grades, 4 'C' Grades, and 6 'D' Grades ' when NYAL 27==1, then the percentage readout should be A = 25%, B=50%, C=20%, and D=30%. The percentage column should divide the count for each grade when NYAL 27=1 by the total count of NYAL 27 =1. As it is now, the project divides grades when NYAL 27=1 by the total number of grades when NYAL 27 has any value.

Comment: @rogues77 Can you check if the updated answer is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to create a 'PERC column, get the `mean` of logical vector and multiply by 100

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    transmute(Categ = "NYAL 27", Grade, COUNT = `NYAL 27`,
              PERC = case_when(COUNT ==1  ~ 100 *mean(COUNT == 1), TRUE ~ 0))
#    Categ Grade COUNT PERC
#1 NYAL 27     A     1   50
#2 NYAL 27     D     0    0
#3 NYAL 27     B     0    0
#4 NYAL 27     C     1   50
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Layer = c("Top", "Bottom", "Middle", "Bottom"), 
    Grade = c("A", "D", "B", "C"), Players = c("NY 08; NY 27; NY 80", 
    "MA 27; MA 45; MA 65", "NY 09; MA 48; NY 66", "NY 06; NY 27; NY 80"
    ), `NYAL 27` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: So when I try the solution (using my data), I get a read out like this

```
      Categ Grade COUNT   PERC
1   NYAL 27       B     1 14.28571
2   NYAL 27       A     1 14.28571
3   NYAL 27       B     1 14.28571
4   NYAL 27       A     1 14.28571
5   NYAL 27       A     1 14.28571
6   NYAL 27       B     1 14.28571
7   NYAL 27       B     1 14.28571
8   NYAL 27       A     1 14.28571
9   NYAL 27       B     1 14.28571
10  NYAL 27       B     0  0.00000
```
So I believe that it is only showing the percentage as the % of the overall data set that NYAL 27 appears.

Comment: @rogues77 From the comments, it is not clear about the output showed

Comment: ```
Categ Grade COUNT   PERC
1   NYAL 27       B     1 14.28571
2   NYAL 27       A     1 14.28571
3   NYAL 27       B     1 14.28571
4   NYAL 27       A     1 14.28571
5   NYAL 27       A     1 14.28571
6   NYAL 27       B     1 14.28571
7   NYAL 27       B     1 14.28571
8   NYAL 27       A     1 14.28571
9   NYAL 27       B     1 14.28571
10  NYAL 27       B     0  0.00000
```

I can try to message you if it's not clear in this format.

Comment: @rogues77 can you able to post the full example in github and sent the link.  In that way, I can copy/paste and test.  Also, please do mention the expected for at tleast couple of columns

Comment: @rogues77 what would be the expected percentage for the whole dataset?

Comment: hold on, I think it might be easier if I just subset and then run summary stats on the new subset. So would it be possible to just create a new dataframe where NYAL 27 =1? If so, how could I do that? I think I'm a little lost because the column name has a space in it

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2020)
df <-  data.frame(
   Grade = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 100, replace = TRUE),
   NYAL_27 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

df %>% 
   filter(NYAL_27 == 1) %>% 
   pull(Grade) %>% 
   table(.) %>% 
   prop.table(.) * 100
#> .
#>        A        B        C        D 
#> 27.65957 34.04255 14.89362 23.40426
```